# Convert url (contains dots) to relative

Tags: php, url, path, sanitize

is there any php functions, to sanitize link+path?
i.e.

```
http://example.com/fold1/fold2/fold3/../../././MyFile.HTML
to
http://example.com/fold1/MyFile.HTML
```

so, i want remove dots,but maintain the suitable(relative) correct path.

Answer (score 0):

I've found so far, is :

```
echo ConvertDotedPathToNormalUrl('http://example.com/directory/.././pageee.html');
```

code:

```
function ConvertDotedPathToNormalUrl($url){
    $firstType = '/(.*)\/((?:(?!\.\.).)+)\/\.\.\//si';
    preg_match($firstType,$url,$result); 
    if (!empty($result[2])){
        $url = str_replace('/'.$result[2].'/..','',$url);
        if ( strstr($url,'../')){$url= ConvertDotedPathToNormalUrl($url);} 
    }
    $url = str_replace('/./','/',$url); $url = str_replace('://','|||',$url);$url = str_replace('//','/',$url);$url = str_replace('|||','://',$url);
    return $url;
}
```

p.s. but not, it converts

Answer (score 0):

You can
1) get the $path using parse_url(..).
2) get the $webroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
3) get the $zrealpath = realpath($webroot . $path);

```
<?php
  define ('CRLF', "<br />\n");
  $url = 'http://example.com/fold1/fold2/fold3/../../././MyFile.HTML';
  $parsed = parse_url($url);
  echo '---- vardump($parsed):', CRLF; // for education
  zvardump($parsed);
  $webroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  echo 'webroot = ', $webroot, CRLF;
  $path = $parsed['path'];
  echo 'path = ', $path, CRLF;
  $zrealpath = realpath($webroot . $path);
  echo 'realpath = ', $zrealpath, CRLF;

function zvardump($var1) {
  ob_start();
  echo "<pre style=\"margin:0;\">\n";
  var_dump($var1);
  echo "</pre>\n";
  $zoutput = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  echo str_replace("=>\n  ", " => ", $zoutput);
  }
?>
```